# optimize() giving different answers?

Tags: r, function, optimization

Below, I'm trying to solve for `ncp` (there is one answer). But I'm wondering why when I extend the `interval` argument in `optimize` the answer drastically changes?

Could I use `uniroot` instead of `optimize` here?

```
f <- function(pwr, q, df1, df2, ncp){
 abs(pwr - pf(q, df1, df2, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE))
}

optimize(f, interval = c(0, 1e2), pwr = .8, q = 2.5, df1 = 3, df2 = 108)[[1]]
# [1] 10.54639  !!! HERE

optimize(f, interval = c(0, 5e2), pwr = .8, q = 2.5, df1 = 3, df2 = 108)[[1]]
# [1] 499.9999  !!! HERE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the rightmost part of the curve is too flat - all values beyond 150 are identical.

Utility function:

```
f2 <- function(x) f(x, pwr = .8, q = 2.5, df1 = 3, df2 = 108)
cc <- curve(f2(x)-0.2,from=150,to=500)
unique(cc$y)
## [1] -5.551115e-17
```

`uniroot()` does indeed work fine: we have to change the function `f` to return a signed value .

```
f <- function(pwr, q, df1, df2, ncp){
   pwr - pf(q, df1, df2, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)
}
uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 5e2), pwr = .8, q = 2.5, df1 = 3, df2 = 108)
## $root
## [1] 10.54641
## $f.root
## [1] -3.806001e-08 
## etc.
```

In general, converting root-finding problems to minimum-finding problems by squaring or taking the absolute value is a fragile strategy (I read about this in *Numerical Recipes* years ago ...)